# c# & linq to sql: using datagrid to add multiple records

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagrid, submit

I have a business policy im trying to implement in order to enter test results into a database. What I need to do is first determine how many entries are required, example:

4 tests per pallet on hold. 5 pallets on hold requires 20 tests.

From here I want to create a datagrid that has 20 rows and 5 columns (one for each relevant piece of info). Every row is required before being able to submit the form.

So my question is two-fold i guess. 
a) how do i create the grid with x amount of rows and 5 columns. no more, no less.
b) how do i use that to insert each row as a record to the database context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, tested and working. In design mode i set the datagrid so that users cannot add additional rows. I also set the columns/names/etc. Then:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Coke_Hold_Database
{
    public partial class frmEnterTestResult : Form
    {
        Record_HoldData thisHold = new Record_HoldData();


        linqCokeDBDataContext db = new linqCokeDBDataContext();

        public frmEnterTestResult(Record_HoldData hold)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.thisHold = hold;


            //sample
            int palletSize = 96;
            int palletsOnHold = Math.Abs(thisHold.HoldQty / palletSize);
            int requiredSamples = palletsOnHold * 4;  


            //create datagrid rows?
            for (short i = 0; i < requiredSamples; i++)
            {
                dgTestResults.Rows.Add();
            }

            //fill the grid widths
            dgTestResults.Columns[0].FillWeight = 30;
            dgTestResults.Columns[1].FillWeight = 30;
            dgTestResults.Columns[2].FillWeight = 30;
            dgTestResults.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create a list that will store each row as an object
            List<Record_TestResult> testResultList = new List<Record_TestResult>();

            //create an object for every row
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgTestResults.Rows)
            {
                //create a new object 
                Record_TestResult results = new Record_TestResult();

                //set the details of the hold in the object
                results.HoldID = thisHold.HoldID;
                results.type = thisHold.NonConformingItem;
                results.entryTime = DateTime.Now;

                //traverse the grid and update the object values from user input
                results.productTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Cells[0].Value);
                results.result = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Cells[1].Value);
                results.pass = Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[2].Value);
                results.testedBy = 1002; //stub

                //add the completed object to the list
                testResultList.Add(results);
            }

            //add the list to what LINQ will submit and then submit
            db.Record_TestResults.InsertAllOnSubmit(testResultList);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One piece of the puzzle is a cartesian product. You could insert your 4 tests into a 'temp_tests' table, and your 5 pallets into a 'temp_pallets' table, then `select * from temp_tests, temp_pallets` to give you a cartesian product of 4 * 5 = 20 rows. Then you'd have to group the rows back into a nice table of (I presume) 4 columns (the tests) of 5 rows (the pallets). How you do that is VERY implementation dependant. Which RDBMS are you using?

Alternately, you *could* write a "generic" testing matrix (fundamentally a "decision grid" (google that)), and just treat the test-names and 'pallets' (in this case) as "labels" on the grid... then all you'd need is way to feed data from the generic grid (of-all-strings) to the specific test... ergo a "parser"... one per distinct set-of-test-case-arguments.

Does any of that make sense to you?

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: using sql server. yes it made sense to me but i think you missed the meat of the question. Really what im getting at is that i'll create the datagrid in c# (figured that part out), the available rows will be determined programatically (figured that out), the user will fill in the datagrid and hit submit, then i need to submit each row from the grid into the database as a new record via LINQ

Comment: OK, so what database-structure where you thinking of storing the (arbitrary) user-entered test data from the grid? (is that right?) I'm thinking you'd need a table-per-grid (with appropriate columns)... or maybe you could store all datatypes as string, and then parse them on the way back out (a reader per "grid")... or maybe you'd be better-off saving all records as an XML document in a single CLOB field... or maybe rows of doclet's (one row per test-case). I'm really not sure how'd I do it... but I guess I'd try rows-of-doclets, as that seems flexible and (fairly) easy.